# How to add one time session message then display to user

Tags: php

I have a small class to show flash notifications below

```
class Flash
{

    const SUCCESS = 'success';
    const INFO = 'info';
    const WARNING = 'warning';


    public static function addMessage(string $message, string $type = 'success'): void
    {
        // Create array in the session if it doesn't already exist
        if (! isset($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])) {
            $_SESSION['flash_notifications'] = [];
        }

        // Append the message to the array
        $_SESSION['flash_notifications'][] = [
            'body' => $message,
            'type' => $type
        ];
    }


    public static function getMessages(): mixed
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])) {
            $messages = $_SESSION['flash_notifications'];
            unset($_SESSION['flash_notifications']);

            return $messages;
        }
    }
```

then when i add the message to session in example below

```
if(empty($_POST['email'])){

   //do something here

} else {
  
    Flash::addMessage('Successful', Flash::SUCCESS);
}
```

then if there is a message display it

```
<?php foreach (Flash::getMessages() as $message): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?= $message['type'] ?>">
        <?= $message['body'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but I receive the following on page load

```
Uncaught TypeError: Flash::getMessages(): Return value must be of type mixed, none returned
```

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notifications'])) {....}` , but what about else ?